# How do I migrate my existing app, plugin or host-editable module project to AndroidX?

Tags: flutter

I am unable to follow the steps here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration

I don't see "Migrate to AndroidX " from the Refactor menu.
In fact I don't know where the Refactor menu is on Android Studio

What should I do?

Update : 
Thank you Haniel for showing me where "migrate to AndroidX is", but that didn't work either. It kept saying "No Usages Found in the Project"

I followed the steps from the highest-rated answer here :
[Unable to migrate Flutter project to AndroidX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54395491/unable-to-migrate-flutter-project-to-androidx/54618207#54618207)

Open the Flutter project into Android Studio
Right-click on the android directory.
Click on Flutter -> Open Android module in Android Studio. 
It asked me to upgrade my gradle plugin. There was an error, so I did this:

Added these given two lines(below) to gradle.properties:-

> android.useAndroidX=true 
>   android.enableJetifier=true

After that, I did Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX.

Answer (score 1):

Let first check if your project is using AndroidX.

In an app or module project, the file `android/gradle.properties` or `.android/gradle.properties` must contain:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

If it is not the case, **Android Studio Project** > **Refactor** > **Migrate to AndroidX...**

[image]